# Performance boost for MacBook: Hybrid hard drive or 4GB RAM?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, performance, memory

I have an aluminium 13" MacBook with 2GB or RAM and 5400RPM 500GB hard drive. The main tasks I perform are developing iPhone and Mac apps in Xcode and websites in Coda.

I want to improve the performance so I am considering buying 4GB of RAM or a 500GB Seagate solid-state hybrid drive. What is likely to provide the biggest performance boost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given just 2GB of RAM and the tasks you're doing, it sounds much more likely that you're RAM-constrained rather than disk I/O performance-constrained.

Comment: I agree, you need more RAM.  Why not get both?

Comment: You can check your free memory on Activity Monitor's System Memory tab. But, yeah, what they said.

Comment: Look for Page Outs on Activity Monitor as a good indicator if you need more RAM. But with 2GB, you most likely do. http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/26